# Why does bash ignore a '-' in a sequence brace expansion?

Tags: bash, sequence

This yields all numbers between 1 and 10

```
echo {1..10}
```

This one yields all odd numbers between 1 and 10 (increment/step value is 2)

```
echo {1..10..2}
```

I experimented a bit, and it turned out if I prefix the increment by a `-` sign, it has no effect

```
echo {1..10..-2}
```

Why is this accepted, rather than being an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimentation with Bash 4.1 (as opposed to the 3.2 version installed by default on the machine I'm using, which does not recognize the notation as special) shows:

```
$ echo {12..10..2}
12 10
$ echo {12..10..-2}
12 10
$ echo {12..-10..2}
12 10 8 6 4 2 0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10
$ echo {12..-10..-2}
12 10 8 6 4 2 0 -2 -4 -6 -8 -10
$ echo {-12..-10..-2}
-12 -10
$ echo {-12..-10..2}
-12 -10
$
```

So, it seems that the direction of the incrementing is controlled by the first two numbers; the magnitude of the incrementing is controlled by the third (defaulting to 1 if the third is missing).

Comment: I meant to only talk about the step having a `-` prepended, not one of the limits :( Why does it take the magnitude instead of just errorring out? When designing a new language, what would one make choose the magnitude instead of just giving an error?

Comment: @Johannes: not having been a developer of the feature, or anywhere near the developer team, I can't say for sure, but...One reason would to minimize the number of errors; if you can do something sensible without generating an error, do so.

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> When the increment is supplied, it is used as the difference between each term.

So... *technically* the output *does* have a difference of -2 between each term. But you still told it to increment rather than decrement in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I first didn't notice that one sentence. I would think though with that description, that a {1..2..1} should yield "2 1", because 2-1 == 1. But it outputs the same for both -1 and 1. Hmm.. Or perhaps it's just a matter of what one means by "difference"? I could imagine that both "2 1" and "1 2" has difference "1", but then how could you have difference of "-1"??

Comment: @Johannes consider that as "absolute" difference.